# roscore bug Errno8

Tags: roscore, ros-indigo, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a new installation of ROS Indigo on OSX Yosemite.
In a terminal when I enter: roscore   I get the error message:

> ...
> 76, in is_local_address
> local_addresses = ['localhost'] + get_local_addresses()   File
> "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosgraph/network.py",
> line 240, in get_local_addresses
> local_addrs = [host[4][0] for host in
> socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(),
> 0, socket.AF_INET, 0, socket.SOL_TCP)]
> gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

printenv | grep ROS    prints out:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_IP=0.0.0.0
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
```

I have no /etc/hosts file.
ping localhost     works.
I'm just trying to run ROS master and clients locally on my Mac.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220631/roscore-bug-errno8/) by [Fry](https://answers.ros.org/users/25033/fry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2015-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `ROS_IP` is `0.0.0.0`, but I'm pretty sure that's not valid. Also you shouldn't have to set your `ROS_HOSTNAME` to anything by default. But neither of those cause the same problem on my mac.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

William, thanks for you speedy reply.
I took your suggestions and removed both ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME from my
.bashrc file to let them default.
But that got me back to a previous error when entering
roscore
into a terminal, and my computer couldn't ping itself under its own name.
So I added a line in /etc/hosts  of
127.0.0.1           localhost       macbook-pro-2.home
and that did the trick. Now roscore  works.
The hard part is how to get at the /etc/hosts file on a mac. Apple makes this really difficult.
One workaround is: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/
One big victory for ROS answers!

---

Originally posted by [Fry](https://answers.ros.org/users/25033/fry/) with karma: 126 on 2015-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1